# Horizontally align (indent) lists and paragraphs

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation

I'm looking for a way to indent text in the following way:

```
Section Name: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
              sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
              magna aliqua.
              Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
              ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
Another Section: Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
                 velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
```

I'm not really sure how I would go about doing this, does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome, i am not quite sure what you want. Are you looking for a simple `enumerate` list (with alphabetical numeration)?

Comment: Not necessarily, I'd rather have any arbitrary label (like "To show:") and then have the paragraph indented to that level.

Comment: Can you give a practical example using some dummy text (`blindtext`, `lipsum`, or use your fantasy)? How long will the paragraphs be? What about page-breaks? Is `to show`  some kind of heading and recurring?

Comment: I've edited the question with a better example, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `hang` package; two possible solutions are provided.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hang}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newenvironment{tobihang}[1]
 {\begin{labeledpar}{#1: \hspace{-1em}}{#1: \hspace{-1em}}\ignorespaces}
 {\end{labeledpar}}

\newenvironment{tobihangspaced}[1]
 {\begin{labeledlist}{#1: \hspace{-1em}}\item[#1: \hspace{-1em}]\ignorespaces}
 {\end{labeledlist}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{tobihang}{Section Name}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{tobihang}

\begin{tobihang}{Another Section}
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{tobihang}

\begin{tobihangspaced}{Section Name}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
\end{tobihangspaced}

\begin{tobihangspaced}{Another Section}
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
\end{tobihangspaced}

\end{document}
```

[image]

We need explicit `-1em` because `hang` hardwires `\labelsep=1em`.